# How to set up Login View in Python Django?

Tags: django, django-views, passkey

I'm trying to set up passkeys to a testing Django website I made a while back following [this guide](https://github.com/mkalioby/django-passkeys), but at some point I get asked to "In your login view, change the authenticate call to include the request as follows":

```
user=authenticate(request, username=request.POST["username"],password=request.POST["password"])
```

However I don't have a Login view as I'm using this in my urls.py:

```
path("login/", userViews.LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
```

I've tried to look up for guides in how to set up a login view manually but they all get me to the simplified version I'm using already.

Is there  way to add that line regardless?

Otherwise, how do I create a login view manually and how should I change my login.html file?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean how to create login with function based view?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we create a form in forms.py with a username and password then render this form into html template and within our view we can authenticate and then login our user.

HTML template

```
<body>
    {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="">username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="">
        <label for="">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="">
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
```

then handle this form in views.py file by creating loginview for it

```
def loginview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = authenticate(request, username=request.POST["username"],
                            password=request.POST["password"])
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'Logged in successfully')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Logged in Fail')
    return render(request, 'test_app/home.html')
```

url path

```
from .views import loginview
urlpatterns = [
    path('', loginview, name='login'),
]
```

Comment: The problem isn't the lack of template, it's the view that I'm missing.

Comment: oh my bad, edited the answer hope this works for you.